# Can not show jplayer full-screen control on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer

From the developer guide page, jplayer has [noFullWindow](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-noFullWindow) option.

Parameter: Object - Defines the user agent blocklist, which contains regular expressions, which cause the full-screen and restore-screen buttons to be hidden if a match is found.

This object has default value:

```
noFullWindow: {
    msie: /msie [0-6]\./,
    ipad: /ipad.*?os [0-4]\./,
    iphone: /iphone/,
    ipod: /ipod/,
    android_pad: /android [0-3]\.(?!.*?mobile)/,
    android_phone: /android.*?mobile/,
    blackberry: /blackberry/,
    windows_ce: /windows ce/,
    iemobile: /iemobile/,
    webos: /webos/
}
```

I tried to set **noFullWindow** to **null** but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem.
My project is using the old version of jplayer (latest: **2.9.2**, mine: **2.1.0**)

*jplayer* version 2.1.0 has **noFullScreen** option instead of **noFullWindow** option.